# copy command syntax error in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, command-prompt

Basically I am just trying to create a `batch file` to copy one file from one location to another location in Windows XP like the code below but **failed**. May I know why?

```
copy C:/Directory_A/the_file D:/Directory_B
```

When I execute the `batch file` I see this in the output:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Comment: Windows uses backslashes (not forward slashes) as a path separator, but will accept the forward slash too. What you've shown would not cause an error, which means that obviously your real command doesn't use `C:/Directory_A` or some other part of the sample code. You need to post the actual command you're trying to use, or at least a better representation of it.

Comment: @Ken White: Not true. Try it for yourself. copy will fail using forwardslashes, since it confuses them with the / for options.

Comment: @shinjin: Works fine here, using real directories.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2005/06/24/432386.aspx

Comment: @Ken White: [Not here](http://i49.tinypic.com/t6ql8z.jpg), using Windows 7, 64 bit

Comment: @shinjin The question is about XP not Win 7

Comment: @shinjin: See the article PhoenixReborn linked, especially the note at the end about either one being accepted. Then read the tags for this question, which mention `windows-xp` - your results on Win7 64 don't matter. :-)

Comment: @PhoenixReborn: Excellent link. I'd forgotten about Larry's blog post about this subject; nice blast from the past. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite - Glad to be of service :-) My google-fu was just a bit stronger than usual tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using backslashes

```
copy C:\Directory_A\the_file D:\Directory_B
```

Comment: Windows XP accepts either the forward or back slash. This isn't the issue (as I mentioned in my comment above).

Comment: Logically speaking yes. I just did an experiment, Windows XP doesn't accept forward slash, is it because this is done using `batch file`? No choice, I must use backslash. When come to a directory that have space in between, I must put within double-quote.